# Find a function or an expression to get a number smaller than 1 for small numbers, and greater than 1 for large numbers

Tags: analysis

I want to come up with a function, or an expression that gives me a number slightly smaller than 1 (0.5, 0.7, 0.9) for smaller numbers (2,3,4..) but larger than 1 for larger numbers.

```
fn(x) = 
        1.1 : x=1
        1.6 : x=2
        2.2 : x=3
        2.8 : x=4
        3.4 : x=5
        3.9 : x=6
        4.5 : x=7
        5.1 : x=8
        5.6 : x=9
        6.2 : x=10
```

How do I go about finding such a function or an expression? It doesn't have to be exactly those values but something I can work with.

Application is that I have an HTML input element whose width I want to be equal to its contents. Simply setting `width=length em` doesn't solve it. But I have found that width and length have above mentioned relationship. (`width = length - 0.5` for length~=2; `width = length - 2` for length=9;... ) I know it's probably not the best approach.

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. But that is wildly discontinuous at $x=-c$, so it is unusable - so surely you either get only half what you want, or you get both, but with a gap in the middle!

Comment: How about using the logarithmic function for the interval (1, infinite) and the same number for the interval (-1, 1) and again logarithmic function after taking modulus in the interval (-infinity,-1)

Comment: You could try something simple like $\dfrac{x}{5}$ or $\dfrac{x^{0.8}}{4}$

Comment: Are you happy to patch together two pieces (which a mathematician might regard as ugly) - presumably you are if it is fast to calculate?

Comment: @almagest, i didn't graph the function and i made a ugly mistake, sorry, this is more like what i meant: $f(x)=a+b*(x-d)/(1.0+c∗|x−d|)$, it's graph is a translated sigmoid.

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. Of course! A sigmoid! That is an elegant solution, which could be made to fit whatever the detail almost whatever it was. I am half-asleep or worse :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a linear fit has provided the following: $f(x)=0.26484+0.12047x$
but i'm not sure that this is sufficient for your application, you'd have to provide more data

i see the user has provided more data, accurately this time, so here is your function:
$f(x)=0.507+0.570x$

Comment: +1 for your sigmoid. Unfortunately, he has probably provided us with enough data to design fairly accurately with his explanation about html. But I just do not feel in the mood to go into that. I spent a frustrating hour with css yesterday :(

Comment: I updates with more accurate and complete data. (atleast the values that I care about). Also, did you come up with it from the equation you gave in the comment? Could you possibly elaborate which of the variable (a,b,c,d,e) dictate which (initial/final) deviations?

Comment: @laggingreflex  i updated the function, apparently there is no need for such a complex function, your data is almost perfectly linear.